# Jumping inputs in inline form Bootstrap 3

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, inline

I work on a project in Bootstrap 3 and I have a problem with my inline form.

I test in different monitors sizes and the problem is on very big screen. My inputs jumps on the row (the inputs now appearing in one row-each inputs appear in one row).

My HTML:

```
<form class="form-inline custom-form" role="form">
  <div class="form-group ">
    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Enter email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group ">
    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword2">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2" placeholder="Password">
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><span style="font-family: 'Georgia',sans;">Login</span></button>
</form>
```

I repeat the problem is just in big screen. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Start by setting column width classes on :

```
<div class="col-sm-12>"<form class="form-inline custom-form" role="form">...</div>
```

Make the enclosed tags add up to your grid width (12 in this case):

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-6"><label>...</label>
```